# Cannot create directory '/home/jenkins/.m2': Permission denied

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile, devops

I have a docker file with the following mkdir command.

```
RUN mkdir /home/jenkins/.m2
```

While building the docker image i am getting the below error.

```
 mkdir: cannot create directory '/home/jenkins/.m2': Permission denied
```

Below is my dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

ENV REPOSITORY_PATH /home/jenkins/test
ENV JBOSS_HOME /home/jenkins
ENV SEDI_TOOLS_HOME /home/jenkins/install/tools

RUN mkdir /home/jenkins/Application
COPY --chown=jenkins:jenkins  .  /home/jenkins/Application/

RUN chmod ugo+x /home/jenkins/Application/ApplicationParent/build_Application/wildfly.sh

WORKDIR /home/jenkins/Application/ApplicationParent/build_Application
COPY --chown=jenkins:jenkins  ./ApplicationParent/build_Application/.jboss-cli.truststore  /home/jenkins/

WORKDIR /home/jenkins/Application/ApplicationParent/build_Application


USER jenkins

RUN mkdir /home/jenkins/.m2
CMD ["/home/jenkins/maven/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/mvn","package","-DskipTests"]
```

Can somebody please help me on this?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide the relevant parts of your dockerfile.

Comment: @leopal Please find it it the question. I have updated it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

In the dockerfile create a new use jenkins to resolve this permission issue as below:

```
# Create new jenkins user
RUN adduser --gecos "" --disabled-password --quiet jenkins
RUN echo "jenkins:jenkins" | chpasswd
```

And change permission of the directory /home/jenkins to user jenkins as below:

```
RUN chown jenkins:jenkins /home/jenkins
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not creating `jenkins` user in your Dockerfile? and `/home/jenkins/` is created by `root` user so as a result, Jenkins user will get permission denied.

Also, Will suggest to offical Jenkins image instead of messing with ubuntu that is lightweight based on [alpine](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/Dockerfile-alpine).

So better to create based on offical image and extend the image as per you need.

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:alpine
.
.
.
```

The alpine base image is only just **160MB**, then you need to use such heavy image and the main thing on your side?

Btw you can try below if you want to go with heavy images.

```
RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos '' jenkins
USER jenkins
RUN mkdir /home/jenkins/Application
COPY  .  /home/jenkins/Application/
RUN chmod ugo+x /home/jenkins/Application/ApplicationParent/build_Application/wildfly.sh
WORKDIR /home/jenkins/Application/ApplicationParent/build_Application
COPY  ApplicationParent/build_Application/.jboss-cli.truststore  /home/jenkins/
WORKDIR /home/jenkins/Application/ApplicationParent/build_Application
RUN mkdir /home/jenkins/.m2
```